# Nativescript 1.3.0 intsllation issue

Tags: nativescript

I will try my best to explain what I did and where I am right now. I am using window7

What I did for installation.

Installed jdk and updated the environment path variable and created new one JAVA_HOME
Downloaded Gradle and updated the environment path pointing to bin directory of gradle
Installed android sdk with all the specified version, sdk tool, and platform tools.
Created ANDROID_HOME variable.
Remove and Reinstalled Nativescript
Ran tns doctor command and result can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/8EGzLmuV) 
Launched the app via tns run android --emulator and tried on device as well error received was "Unfortunately mysir has stopped" and log can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/RcicsSFX).
Now Can anyone please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check out if `<your app>\platforms\android\src\main\assets\internal\prepareExtend.js` file exists. This file is supposed to be created when you execute `tns platform add android` command. If the file does not exist then it may be better to create a new project.

Comment: It wasn't about any file and It was a new project as mentioned in my comment, which is very hard to read :). I have updated and answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

well the whole problem was I was  not running command `npm install tns-core-modules --save` after creating new project.